# pnpm builds wrong path to webpack.js

Tags: webpack, node-modules, pnpm

pnpm start fails because it builds wrong path to webpack.js This setup was working fine till a few days ago. The only changes were to webpack config to add sharing.
Now
`pnpm start`
outputs

```
nra18@1.0.0 start /mnt/sda6/django/react/nra18
```

Error: Cannot find module '/mnt/sda6/django/nra18/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'

But that path to webpack is wrong since it should be

```
"/mnt/sda6/django/react/nra18/node_modules/..."
```

instead of

```
"/mnt/sda6/django/nra18/node_modules/..."
```

(notice the "react" dir is omitted in the path)

I am using

```
pnpm -v
7.29.1
```

I can run other packages which are soft linked to the same node_modules directory so there is no problem with the directory itself.
when pnpm starts it outputs the directory correctly but then when it builds the path to webpack something goes wrong.
The same setup was working till a few days ago.
Is there any cache or something like that involved which can affect how pnpm locates webpack?